# Whether this pointer comparison is unspecified or equivalent?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this case, which is sourced from https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2018/07/24/pointers-and-bytes.html:

```cpp
int main(){
    auto x = new int[8];
    auto y = new int[8];
    y[0] = 42;
    auto x_ptr = x+8; // one past the end
    if (x_ptr == &y[0]){
         // ...
    }
}
```

Now, imagine that x and y have been allocated right next to each other, with y having the higher address.

According to [expr.eq] p3

> Comparing pointers is defined as follows:
>
> > - If one pointer represents the address of **a complete object**, and another pointer represents the address one past the last element of a different complete object, the result of the comparison is unspecified.
> > - Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both **represent the same address**, they compare equal.

neither `x` nor `y` points to a **complete object**, they initially point to the element of the arrays, which is a subobject. So, it seems that the first bullet does not apply to this case. So, the second bullet applies here since `y` is immediately after the array that `x` initially points to. So, the comparison is `true`, right?

Comment: @NathanOliver The `int` object is not a complete object since it is the subobject of the array, i.e. the first element of the array. Then you can see `An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a complete object.` in the standard.

Comment: My bad, had this confused with something else

Comment: [intro.object/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#2) The allocated arrays are complete objects, array elements are subobjects. *An object that is not a subobject of any other object is called a complete object.* `x` and `y` point to complete objects.

Comment: Maybe "points to" != "represents the address of"? Sure `y` doesn't point to a complete object, but maybe it represents its address?

Comment: @273K But `x`,`y` point to array elements, not whole arrays, therefore not to complete objects?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, they point to array elements, but they *represent the addresses of **complete objects***.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object **represents the address of the first byte** in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively.* Notice the subtle in the second bullet, it only compares the address the pointers represent.

Comment: You ASSUME that `y` has the higher address.  There's no guarantee of that at all.  Remember that stacks grow toward lower addresses.  The compiler might very well allocate them in the opposite order.

Comment: @xmh0511 Ok, so we have the answer then? "points to" != "represents address", `y` doesn't point to a complete object but it represents its address, because it's numerically equal to the address of the whole array.

Comment: The definition of [representing an address](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:represents_the_address), Note 2: "A pointer past the end of an object is not considered to point to an unrelated object of the object's type, even if the unrelated object is located at that address."

Answer (score 5):

"Points to" != "represents the address of". In the first bullet:

> If one pointer **represents the address** of a complete object...

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

`y` doesn't "point to" a complete object (it points to an array element, aka its subobject), but `y` does "represent the address" of a complete object, because it's numerically equal to the address of the whole array.

From the paragraph you posted in the comments: [`[basic.compound]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#compound-3)

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object<sup>34</sup> or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively.

Comment: 34) "For an object that is not within its lifetime, this is the first byte in memory that it will occupy or used to occupy." (also added superscript to make the footnote reference clear)

Comment: @xmh0511 "First byte in memory" occupied by `y[0]` is the same byte as the "first byte in memory" occupied by the whole `y`. That's the same byte, therefore its address is the same address.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So, your answers is that the result of the comparison is unspecified due to the first bullet?

Comment: @xmh0511 Yep, exactly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the edit. What do you mean by that quote? Where is it in the standard?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, so the analysis in the blog is wrong.

Comment: @xmh0511 What analysis? I didn't read all of it, but it seems they're talking about something completely different. If two pointers "represent the same address", it doesn't necessarily mean that you can dereference and write to one, and observe the result through the other.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - sorry, the "Quote" is Footnote 34 from the standard that you referenced in your answer. And, yes, the last comment is precisely the subtle point that should probably be made clear. The reference of the address of one-past-the-end is fine for address comparison, but you cannot attempt to access the value without stumbling head-long into UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *What analysis?* The analysis in the blog supposes` if (x_ptr == &y[0])`  is always true, however, the result is unspecified in C++ as per your answers.

Comment: @xmh0511 They don't say it's always true, they just show what happens if it happens to be true.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to the first element of an array is the "address of a complete object", if that array is not contained in any other object.

The text does apply to the situation. The comparison has unspecified behavior.

It has to be specified because none of these options is reasonable:

- Making it undefined. Why? Who needs another footgun.
- Making it implementation-defined. Problem is, the implementation then has to document how the behavior occurs, revealing all the implementation details of how the allocator works under all circumstances.
- Making it well defined is out of the question. Making it always false would mean that objects cannot be compactly allocated: there has to be at least a byte of space (plus alignment) wasted after each object to make sure that the "one past" pointer isn't the address of any other object. Making it always true would be impossible; it cannot be true for all pairs of objects.

Unspecified is best. That means the comparison is either true or false, but the implementation doesn't have to specify how the choice is made. Thus it can just be naturally left to chance: if the objects are consecutively and compactly allocated in that order, then it turns out true, otherwise not.

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong, it doesn't matter if the array is a complete object or not (because `y` doesn't point to it anyway, it points to its element). What if the array is the first member of a struct? It's no longer complete, but this rule still must apply.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If the array is the first member of a struct, then the pointer to the first element of the array, is the address of the struct.  If the struct is a complete object, then the pointer is the address of a complete object.